# Excel Format Painter but for Number Format Only

Tags: excel

Whenever I want to make a number format of a cell same with another cell that I wanted, I always use the Format Cell, and then copy the number format like on this picture.

[image: picture]

But, it is not simple, so I tried to use format painter to make it faster, but the problem is, with the format painter, all the cell format, including the merge, cell color, font color, etc. is also included.

So the question is: Is there a way to use format painter without pasting the merge, cell color, etc. but only pasting the Number Format?

Comment: I don't think `Paste Special Formula and Number Format` is what am I looking for, because i only need paste the number format, not with the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use cell styles for this. Create a new cell style and in the dialog untick all the formatting options you don't want to include, i.e. keep only the number format.

After that, you can have all kinds of font/fill/whatever format and apply the style to the cell. The number format will be applied, but the font/fill/whatever remains as is.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

luffy92! alternative to teylyn 's method, I would do the following step.

I don't use copy-paste, instead, I would simply select all the values, and apply the custom cell formatting you have shown yourself in the picture.

Smile.

Comment: I think luffy92 knows how to do that, but rather wants to avoid the multiple click steps through the number format dialgo.